# Program not outputting variable

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and want to make a simple program to find common factors between 2 numbers. I am using MSYS2 to compile. My code compiles with no errors, however the program won't output anything after defining the lrg variable
Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int num1;
    int num2;
    std::cout << "Enter the first number:";
    std::cin >> num1;
    std::cout << "Enter the second number:";
    std::cin >> num2;
    int lrg = std::max(num1, num2);
    std::cout << "The largest number is " << lrg;
    for (int i = 0; i < lrg; i++) {
        if (num1 % i == 0 && num2 % i == 0) {
            std::cout << i;
        };
    };
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run I do not get the largest number nor the common factors.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Maybe you should start your loop at 1 so you don't have division by zero.. Better yet start at 2.

Comment: Why do you do std::cout when you are already including the namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first operation of the for loop will divide by 0, in c++ x / y or x% y is *undefined behavior*

That means it can do just about anything, from inexplicably crashing to inexplicably working, to all kinds of stuff in between. You might expect in some environments an exception to be thrown, but that's not guaranteed by C++, rather, by the implementation.

So you're not calculating the factors correctly, and that's the chief problem. Some side stuff:

(thanks John 3136!)It's probably always a good idea to use std::endl at the end of a cout statement that you intend to be read immediately in the console. When you have a statement like:

```
std::cout << "The largest number is " << lrg;
```

You're writing to a buffer, not directly to whatever the device is (generally in c++ std::cout is writing to standard output, but even that can be redirected). When that buffer is actually sent to the device is implementation-defined, but generally you don't want to write every single byte byte-by-byte. You buffer some, then write. This is important for, say, streaming to a file where you may have a huge amount of data, and the performance savings can be big.

endl is special, it writes a newline character and then flushes the stream, meaning it writes everything in the buffer to the device.

```
std::cout << "The largest number is " << lrg << std::endl;
```

This is generally the behavior you want when writing to a console window (but maybe not when writing to a file, flushing the buffer every single line is unnecessarily expensive, and since you're not reading the file as it's being written it may not be worth it).

Now, there are a few nuances, in some implementations output to a terminal is always flushed. Cin is tied to cout (possibly only since C++11?) so that cout is flushed when you call cin, so you don't have a blank prompt for input (so your first set of cout/cins would be covered by that). However, without doing it yourself (usually with endl) there technically isn't a guarantee your message will show up on the console when you needed it to.

Next: the for and if blocks don't need semicolons after the closing bracket. They don't hurt anything in this particular instance (they're just empty statements, like a semicolon all by itself on a line) but it's a bad habit. When you see that you expect to see something like a brace-enclosed initialization list, or a class or object definition.

Finally, you use

```
using namespace std;
```

but still fully qualify all the names. Not technically an error, but again, make sure you understand what the using statement does. It's actually often considered *good* to get into the habit of fully qualifying names in the std namespace, as you do. I'd say, just as a matter of clear intent, if you intend to qualify all the names then don't dump in the namespace.

Comment: Suggest you address why this line `std::cout << "The largest number is " << lrg;` doesn't output...

Comment: Hmm, in MSVC15 it gets past that line and displays the largest value before the divide by 0. I interpreted his question to mean it successfully got past the assignment and the display. Am I missing something?

Comment: since there is no `std::endl` it is possible that no output will appear (it could be buffered and the the exe crashes as you describe) without flushing the buffer.